# In what situations are 'out' parameters useful (where 'ref' couldn't be used instead)?

Tags: c#, out-parameters, ref-parameters

As far as I can tell, the only use for `out` parameters is that a caller can obtain multiple return values from a single method invocation. But we can also obtain multiple result values using `ref` parameters instead!

So are there other situations where `out` parameters could prove useful and where we couldn't use `ref` parameters instead?

Thank you.

Comment: NB: I've just posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102892/real-world-examples-where-c-out-parameters-are-useful/7220754#7220754) to a similar question where I describe a scenario where an `out` parameter is useful for something other than returning more than one value from a method.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes - the difference between `ref` and `out` is in terms of definite assignment:

- An `out` parameter *doesn't* have to be definitely assigned by the caller before the method call. It *does* have to be definitely assigned in the method before it returns normally (i.e. without an exception). The variable is then definitely assigned in the caller *after* the call.
- A `ref` parameter *does* have to be definitely assigned by the caller before the method call. It *doesn't* have to be assigned a different value in the method.

So suppose we wanted to change `int.TryParse(string, out int)` to use `ref` instead. Usually the calling code looks like this:

```
int value;
if (int.TryParse(text, out value))
{
    // Use value
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Now if we used `ref`, we'd have to give `value` a value before the call, e.g.:

```
int value = 0;
if (int.TryParse(text, ref value))
{
    // Use value
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Obviously it's not a *huge* difference - but it gives the wrong impression. We're assigning a value that we have no intention of ever using, and that's not a good thing for readability. An `out` parameter indicates that a value *will* come out of the method (assuming there's no exception) and that you don't need to have a value to start with.

Once of the suggestions I've made for C# 5 (I've no idea if it'll be taken up or not) is that a method with an `out` parameter should be able to regarded as a method returning a tuple of values. Combined with better support for tuples, that would mean we could do something like this:

```
var (ok, value) = int.TryParse(text);
```

In this case `ok` and `value` would be implicitly typed to `bool` and `int` respectively. That way it's clear what's going into the method (`text`) and what's coming out (two pieces of information: `ok` and `value`).

That would simply not be available if `int.TryParse` used a `ref` parameter instead - as the compiler can't know whether it's going to *actually* care about the initial value of the `ref` parameter.

Comment: +1 - I like the idea of a tuple result value implied by out parameters.

Comment: @Thomas: It's not original - I pinched it from F# :)

Comment: _(Somewhat off-topic:)_ Agree with Jon on his request for tuple "unpacking" (whatdoyoucallit). I still don't understand why such a big fuss was made about support for tuples in .NET / C# 4.0 -- and that they apparently even had to adapt the CLR for it -- while at the same time that very handy feature was left out. Sort of makes the `Tuple` type look very trivial, if not even nearly useless.

Comment: @stakx: I hadn't heard anything about tuple support requiring a CLR change. Do you have a link for further information?

Comment: @stakx: Tuples were mainly added to the BCL in order to unify the different, incompatible *existing* Tuple types from all the .NET languages that have Tuples natively, like Python or F#. Similar to big number arithmetic. I don't think there was ever any intention of surfacing them in any of the languages that didn't already support them. Not that that wouldn't be great, of course. Ideally with even more general pattern matching or at least general destructuring bind, not just for Tuples.

Comment: @Jeff I really hope they implement your suggestion. It's one of my favorite features of Python. Saves a lot of throw-away-class creation and unnecessary packing/unpacking.

Comment: @Jon: I heard about about tuples and the CLR in a PDC 2008 session recording ("Microsoft .NET Framework: CLR Futures", online @ http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC49/). My comment above is due to one inaccurate slide in that talk: While the slide presented around time index 00:13:15 suggests that the *CLR* was changed to allow tuples, a later slide (around time index 00:16:06) states that tuples were included in the *BCL* for interoperability (basically what Jörg commented above). That makes far better sense, too. (Still a bit strange to hear about the BCL in a talk about the CLR...)

Answer (score 8):

You can look at parameters in this way:

- **normal parameters are *in* parameters:**
   A value can go into the function through such a parameter; therefore it must be initialized.
- **`ref` parameters are *in-out* parameters:**
   A value can go into and out of a function through such a parameter. Because of the former, it must also be initialized.
- **`out` parameters are *out* parameters:**
   A value is only supposed to come back from a function through such a parameter; therefore, it doesn't need to be initialized.

I came up with this way of looking at `ref`/`out` parameters by studying Microsoft's COM technology. IDL (interface description language) is used to describe COM component interfaces, and with IDL, parameters are augmented with `in`, `out`, and `inout` declarators. I suspect .NET and C# have partly inherited these declarators from COM, albeit with slightly different names (`ref` instead of `inout`).

With COM, `out` parameters are frequently used to retrieve an interface method's actual return value, since the "real" return value is often already used for returning a `HRESULT` success/error code.

With .NET, I think `out` parameters have far less importance, even in cases where you want to return several values from a method (you could return complex objects or `Tuple`s in these situations).

Answer (score 4):

One important difference is this:

> A variable passed as an out argument
>   need not be initialized. However, the
>   out parameter must be assigned a value
>   before the method returns.

(A ref parameter does not require this)

Source:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

An `out` parameter is useful when you want multiple result values from a method. Technically, you could use a `ref` parameter to achieve the same goal but an `out` parameter does a significantly better job at conveying intent. When you use `ref`, It is not clear why you are doing so instead of using `out` or instead of using the function result. Presumably, you intend on changing the value passed, but why you are changing it isn't clear simply from the function signature.

Answer (score 2):

I think a fine example is int.TryParse()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

The primary reason that **out** is better than **ref** is that you don't need to assign a dummy value to the return var before calling (even implicitly).

So **out** tells you, and the compiler: "This var will be assigned within the method.  And the var's initial value, if any, will not even be looked at."

Answer (score 0):

Major difference between the two is that if we are using **ref** then we have to initialize this before call and it is optional that we assign a value to our **ref** variable in our method.

However for **out** methods we do not have to explicitly initialize them but in our method we have to assign some value to it, otherwise they will generate compile time error.