# Real-world examples where C# 'out' parameters are useful?

Tags: c#, out-parameters

I'm reading up on core C# programming constructs and having a hard time wrapping my head around the `out` parameter modifier. I know what it does by reading but am trying to think of a scenerio when I would use it.

Can someone give me a real-world example? Thanks.

Comment: Int32.TryParse is a good example.

Comment: Worth noting, and perhaps somebody will edit it into their answer, but using `out` requires that you set the value inside the method, unlike `ref`, which may or may not actually be modified. If you write a method with an `out` parameter, you will get an error unless the compiler can verify that all possible code paths result in the value being set. This is behavior you can then rely upon as a consumer of that method.

Comment: when you need one or more returning values from a method, you would rather go for out parameter instead of creating a modal class and return that. as said by @vcsjones  `Int32.TryParse` is a good example, because it returns a `bool` to tell whether the parsing was successful or not, and it also returns an `out` parameter with the value filled in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

there are many scenarios where you would use it, but the main one would be where your method needs to return more then one parameter.  Take, for example, the `TryParse` methods on `int` type.  In this case, instead of throwing an exception a bool is returned as a success/failure flag and the parsed int is return as the out param.  if you were to call `int.Parse(...)` you could potentially throw an exception.

```
string str = "123456";
int val;
if ( !int.TryParse(str,out val) )
{
// do some error handling, notify user, etc.
}
```

Comment: This is a very simple and great answer: when you need a method to return more than one parameter.

Answer (score 19):

The main motivation to using an `out` parameter is to allow a function to return multiple values to the caller and everyone else provided examples in the framework.  I'll take a different approach to answering your question by exploring the reasoning behind having `out` parameters in the first place.  I won't write out actual examples but describe them.

Normally you have only one mechanism to return values, the function's return value.  Sure you could use a global (static) or instance variables too but that's not very practical nor safe to do in general (for reasons I won't explain here).  *Prior to .NET 3.5*, there wasn't a really practical way to return multiple values from a function.  If `out` or `ref` modifiers were not available, you would have a few options:

- If all your values had the same type, you could return some collection of the values.  This is perfectly fine in most cases, you could return an array of number, list of strings, whatever.  This is perfect if all the values were related in exactly the same way.  i.e., All numbers were the number of items in a container, or the list was of names of guests at a party.  But what if the values you returned represented different quantities?  What if they had different types?  A list of objects could hold them all but it is not a very intuitive way to manipulate that sort of data.
- For the case when you need to return multiple values of different types, the only practical option you had was to create a new class/struct type to encapsulate all these values and return an instance of that type.  Doing so you could return strongly typed values with intuitive names and you could return multiple values this way.  The problem is that in order to get that, you had to define the type with a specific name and everything just to be able to return multiple values.  What if you wanted to return only two values which were simple enough making it impractical to create a type for it?  You have a couple more options again:

  - You could create a set of generic types to contain a fixed amount of values of varying types (like a tuple in functional languages).  But it is not as appealing to do so in a reusable manner since it wasn't part of the framework at the time.  It could be put in a library but now you add a dependency on that library just for the sake of these simple types.  (just be glad that .NET 4.0 now includes the `Tuple` type)  But this still doesn't solve the fact that these are simple values which means added complexity for a simple task.
  - The option that was used was to include an `out` modifier which allows the caller to pass a "reference" to a variable so that the function may set the referenced variable as another way to return a value.  This way of returning values was also available in C and C++ in many ways for the same reasons and played a role in influencing this decision.  However the difference in C# is that for an `out` parameter, the function *must* set the value to something.  If it doesn't, it results in a compiler error.  This makes this less error prone since by having an `out` parameter, you're promising the caller that you will set the value to something and they can use it, the compiler makes sure you stick to that promise.

A note on the typical usage of the `out` (or `ref`) modifier, it will be rare to see more than one or two `out` parameters.  In those cases, it will almost always be a much better idea to create the encapsulating type.  You would typically use it if you needed *just* one more value to return.

However since C#-3.0/.NET-3.5 with the introduction of anonymous types and tuples introduced in .NET 4.0, these options provided alternative methods to return multiple values of varying types easier (and more intuitive) to do.

Comment: +1. Excellent, well written and very complete answer. Even mentioned tuples, which is a good compromise when returned values are explicit enough to not to be named.

Comment: Using `Action<...>` delegates are another option for returning multiple values. The `Int32.Parse` method signature could be rewritten as `bool TryParse(string raw, Action<int> parsed)`. The advantage here is that you can assign values to properties, not just fields and local variables, as well as calling other methods.

Comment: @Enigmativity: That's an interesting case.  Used all the time in LINQ.  I wouldn't class that approach with the ones I've mentioned however.  The key difference is that allows for side effects to occur as well.  On the other hand, what I mention is just a mechanism to transfer data, nothing else.  It has its place in C# but for strictly returning a value, not the place for it IMHO.  It reminds me as achieving the opposite of what the upcoming async programming features will allow us to do.

Comment: @`Jeff M` - Actually it is almost the same thing as the new async features. It is a form of continuation passing which is how the async stuff is implemented. I'd also suggest that `out` and `ref` parameters are an explicitly programming side-effects. Using `Action<...>` is just a more expressive and rich way of allowing side-effects.

Comment: @Enigma: What I was referring to was how the syntax reminded me of how the async callback code had to be written prior to the CTP.  The new `await` keyword kinda reminded me of `out` or `ref` in this case.  But that's not important.  ;)

Answer (score 6):

Sure, take a look at any of the `TryParse` methods, such as [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx):

The idea is you actually want *two* pieces of information: whether a parse operation was successful (the return value), *and*, if so, what the result of it actually was (the `out` parameter).

Usage:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int value;

// First we check the return value, which is a bool
// indicating success or failure.
if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
{
    // On success, we also use the value that was parsed.
    Console.WriteLine(
        "You entered the number {0}, which is {1}.",
        value,
        value % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"
    );
}
else
{
    // Generally, on failure, the value of an out parameter
    // will simply be the default value for the parameter's
    // type (e.g., default(int) == 0). In this scenario you
    // aren't expected to use it.
    Console.WriteLine(
        "You entered '{0}', which is not a valid integer.",
        input
    );
}
```

Many developers complain of `out` parameters as a "code smell"; but they can be by far the most appropriate choice in many scenarios. One very important modern example would be multithreaded code; often an `out` parameter is necessary to permit "atomic" operations where a return value would not suffice.

Consider for example `Monitor.TryEnter(object, ref bool)`, which acquires a lock *and* sets a `bool` atomically, something that wouldn't be possible via a return value alone since the lock acquisition would necessarily happen before the return value were assigned to a `bool` variable. (Yes, technically `ref` and `out` are not the same; but they're very close).

Another good example would be some of the methods available to the collection classes in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace new to .NET 4.0; these provide similarly thread-safe operations such as `ConcurrentQueue<T>.TryDequeue(out T)` and `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryRemove(TKey, out TValue)`.

Answer (score 4):

Output parameters are found all over the .NET framework. Some of the uses I see most often are the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) methods, which return a boolean (indicating whether or not the parse was valid) and the actual result is returned via the output parameter. While it's also very common place to use a class when you need to return multiple values, in such an example as this it's a little heavy handed. For more on output parameters, see Jon Skeet's article on [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html#out).

Answer (score 2):

Simple, when you have a method that returns more than one value.
One of the most "famous" cases is [Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx):

```
string value = "";

if (openWith.TryGetValue("tif", out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("For key = \"tif\", value = {0}.", value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = \"tif\" is not found.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said - out parameters allow us to return more than one value from a method call without having to wrap the results in struct/class.

The addition of the xxx.TryParse methods greatly simplified the coding necessary to convert between a string value (frequently from the UI) and a primitive type.

An example of what you might have had to write to achieve the same functionality is here:

```
/// <summary>
/// Example code for how <see cref="int.TryParse(string,out int)"/> might be implemented.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="integerString">A string to convert to an integer.</param>
/// <param name="result">The result of the parse if the operation was successful.</param>
/// <returns>true if the <paramref name="integerString"/> parameter was successfully 
/// parsed into the <paramref name="result"/> integer; false otherwise.</returns>
public bool TryParse(string integerString, out int result)
{
    try
    {
        result = int.Parse(integerString);
        return true;
    }
    catch (OverflowException)
    {
        // Handle a number that was correctly formatted but 
        // too large to fit into an Int32.
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        // Handle a number that was incorrectly formatted 
        // and so could not be converted to an Int32.
    }

    result = 0; // Default.
    return false;
}
```

The two exception checks that are avoided here make the calling code much more readable. I believe that the actual .NET implementations avoid the exceptions altogether so perform better as well. Similarly, this example shows how IDictionary.TryGetValue(...) makes code simpler and more efficient:

```
private readonly IDictionary<string,int> mDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

public void IncrementCounter(string counterKey)
{
    if(mDictionary.ContainsKey(counterKey))
    {
        int existingCount = mDictionary[counterKey];

        mDictionary[counterKey] = existingCount + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        mDictionary.Add(counterKey, 1);
    }
}

public void TryIncrementCounter(string counterKey)
{
    int existingCount;
    if (mDictionary.TryGetValue(counterKey, out existingCount))
    {
        mDictionary[counterKey] = existingCount + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        mDictionary.Add(counterKey, 1);
    }
}
```

And all thanks to the out parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Int32.TryParse(String, out Int);
```

or something similar like Dictionary.TryGetValue.

But I would consider this one to be a not too good practice to employ it, of course, using those provided by API like the Int32 one to avoid Try-Catch is exceptions.

Comment: Why do you think that using TryGetValue is bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

```
//out key word is used in function instead of return. we can use multiple parameters by using out key word
public void outKeyword(out string Firstname, out string SecondName)
{
    Firstname = "Muhammad";
    SecondName = "Ismail";

}
//on button click Event
protected void btnOutKeyword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string first, second;
    outKeyword(out first, out second);
    lblOutKeyword.Text = first + "  " + second;
}
```