# C# Out Parameter - where class outside of calling method is used

Tags: c#-4.0, out

I'm trying to get to the just of the Out parameter. I have seen [many examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485(v=vs.100).aspx), but they all have a method where there is no new class that is used..

I get 2 errors when calling this test code:

```
The out parameter 'w' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method.
Use of unassigned out parameter 'w'.



public partial class Form1 : Form

{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Widget newWidget;
        Widget.Create(out newWidget);

    }
}
class Widget
{
    private String name;
    public String Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }

    public static void Create(out Widget w)
    {
        w.name = "1";

    }
}
```

This works , but what does it help?

```
  public static void Set(out Widget w)
        {

            Widget x = new Widget();
            x.name = "1";
            w = x;

        }
```

Comment: What is the question? What isn't clear?

Comment: Think Im missing a basic concept, cannot figure out why I am getting the 2 errors mentioned

Comment: The error messages are very clear. Your new (edited) question is again unclear

Comment: i made sense of the error messages now, and fixed the project so it works. Now battling to see what the use of out is, if Im going to create a new Widget in the Create method anyway. But i'll prob have to delete the question as it sounds like i did not ask a good question.

Comment: Don't use `out` here... just return the widget. Unless you're working on really low level code, you do not need to use `out` parameters.

Comment: Im getting quizzed soon on Out parameter for a test, wanted to understand more of the subject. All examples are primitive, wanted to get deeper more realistic understanding on subject.

Comment: All you really need to know about `out` parameters is that the method that declares them _must_ set the parameter to some value, just like a method that returns a value must actually return a value. Nowadays, you never really need to use them as there are better ways to achieve the same result that they were designed to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, with the last code addition i included, would that pass or is it missing the point?

Comment: Yeah, that would work. You declared `w` to be an out parameter, and you set it so it should be fine. If you're still not clear on the purpose of the `out` parameter, I go over the motivations of its inclusion [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4102892/390278). (FYI, if you want to make sure that I get a notification that you left a comment, use `@username` in your comment to make sure it gets to who you want. I wouldn't have seen your comment otherwise, but I just happen to have this question still open)

Answer (score 1):

This code does not make sense. The out parameter are usually used for value types (primitives) and not to reference types.

A value type, for example an int, are copied into a method and updates to this variable does not affect the original one. To update original value you can use the `out` parameter.

You can rewrite your code to look something like this instead.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Widget newWidget = new Widget("nameOfWidget");
    }
}

class Widget
{
    private String name;
    public String Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }

    public Widget(string nameOfWidget)
    {
        name = nameOfWidget;
    }
}
```

Comment: "The out parameter are usually used for value types (primitives) and not to reference types." ...no, the `out` parameter is used for any type, whether it be a value or reference type. You're confusing this with mutable objects or something else.

Comment: Well, I wrote "usually", but I'm aware there could be other case where it actually makes sense. Since the widget in this example is a reference type it is just a very odd way of instantiating the widget class. Maybe he's looking into a factory class/method but it doubt it...

Answer (score 0):

The [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485(v=vs.100).aspx) you mentioned shows only primitive types. Assigning primitive types can be done the following way, both are equal:

```
i = 44;
i = new System.Int32(44);
```

As you can see, a new integer has been created. You have to do the same with your Widget Class before leaving the method. 
Hope this helps to clarify the MSDN examples.